# How to generate Registration no

Tags: user-registration

I want generate registration no of user but registration no should be as

- First two digit no. should be year as - 15
- Second two digit no. should be month as - 06
- Third two should be Character which already assign as - SY
- Fourth should be No as - 012

So my registration no will make as - 1506SY012

How to generate it in php code ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in functions.php

This will automatically add a custom field to a user when they register on your site with a key of: `user_registration_no`

```
 add_action('user_register', 'add_user_registration_number');
    function add_user_registration_number ($user_id) {
        $reg_number = date('y').date('m').'SY'.'0'.$user_id;
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_registration_no', $reg_number);
    }
```

This should be formatted in the way in which you specified..

Comment: Some kind of **proper** explanation would be nice. Something like how the code works and where it should be should and what it actually does :-)